# Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'CategoryId' in table 'Products' is specified more than once. Migration Update Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, datatable, sql-update, database-migration

I am using visual studio with sql server, i am in a middle of a practice and faced a major issue.
The issue was in the first place, when i was creating a product table , by mistake i mistyped as a categoryId ctegoryId, and later i recorrected it by thinking its over.

And now I am almost done with the identity scaffolding when updating my database, I am facing such an error. and I've tried all ways to update it by myself but failed.
I need an expert guidance so I can continue my path till the end.

I do appreciate any solution from your side.

Thanks indeed [[Migration error "Each Table must be unique"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7rhc.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tB3iT.png)

Comment: Include your product class here in your question instead of screenshot.

Comment: What if you run this command `Add-Migration -IgnoreChanges` and then  run `Update-Database`

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know, I have deleted my migration and reinstalled again without[NotMapped]in my product table"categoryID" and it worked back normally.